# shm_open() function is not creating the shared memory

Tags: c, posix

I'm trying to open a shared memory, Its giving me No such file or directory error.
But i have a file as well as a directory in the name region.

```
 fd_sh = shm_open("/home/angus/c_tutorials/interview/linux_sys_pgm/mmap/region", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
 if(fd_sh == -1){
  perror("fd_sh:ERROR");
  return -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Linux (I assume that's your OS, given your code), the name should start with a slash but not have any others afterwards, e.g. `"/myshm"` -- not a regular filename.

From the man page:

```
   The operation of shm_open() is analogous  to  that  of  open(2).   name
   specifies the shared memory object to be created or opened.  For porta‐
   ble use, a shared memory object should be identified by a name  of  the
   form  /somename;  that  is,  a null-terminated string of up to NAME_MAX
   (i.e., 255) characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by  one
   or more characters, none of which are slashes.
```

Doing it this way will work fine.

What in fact happens is that the name given is created as a file in `/dev/shm`, so you would need to create a directory structure to use a path; this is not a good idea since this directory is only in memory.

Comment: I tried with /region , I'm getting a permission denied error. But I'm the root user of the machine.

Comment: I have to store an integer and a string onto the shared memory, i have declared this as a structure. I cant use shmget and use the pointer to store the structure, as the scope of the structure is within the process. So I opted for shm_open(). Is there an alternate way to store the contents of a structure of processA as well as processB into the shared memoryA

Comment: Try running `shm_open` in isolation -- check to see if any file is created in /dev/shm. I haven't looked at shared memory for a while, I'm not sure if there are restrictions on root permissions for security reasons.